# Elements of prime order in symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been assigned the following task:

“Explain briefly why there can be no odd elements of prime order except for order $2$ in any symmetric group $S_n$.”

Unless I am largely mistaken in my understanding of the notions of order and the sign of a permutation, I have come up with the following:

$[3,3,3,1]$ is an element of $S_{10}$ with order $3$, and is even.

$[7, 1, 1]$ is an element of $S_9$ with order $7$, and is odd.

Am I mistaken in thinking that this shows that not only do there exist odd elements of prime order $p≠2$, but also that there exist even elements of order $2$ (the former contradicting the statement in the question)?

Comment: What is this notation: $[3,3,3,1]$?

Comment: Anyway, it's odd, but a cycle of odd length is an *even* permutation..

Comment: @Berci It's the lengths of the disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $7$-cycle is even because we can break it into transpositions $$(a_1,a_7)(a_1,a_6)(a_1,a_5)(a_1,a_4)(a_1,a_3)(a_1,a_2)$$

And as you can see there are six transpositions, so this permutation is even.

Comment: Thank you, it was an oversight on my part that I thought that a cycle of length $7$ consisted of $7$ transpositions.